# How do I make images from this waifu API appear on page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I've been stuck on this Waifu API for a bit now and want to ask for help.

I can get the JSON tags in the console and from there I'm able to navigate, click on the image, and see it. But I'm having trouble formatting it on the page with each click.

I know it's a stupid question, I just wanna make my friends at work laugh but also LEARN WHY IT ISN'T WORKING. :/

thank you for your time

```
<!-- ---waifuthingy----- -->

    <div id="waifuContainer" class="container mt-5 text-center">
        <h1 class="display-5 text-warning" id="dadJokeFont">Click for waifu:</h1>
        <button id="waifuButton" class="btn btn-warning mt-5">uWu</button>
        <div id="waifuImage" >
            <img id="waifus" src="" alt=""> </div>

    </div>

<!-- ----letmebe---- -->
```

```
// Waifu Image API


const waifuImage = document.querySelector('#waifuImage');
const waifuButton = document.querySelector('#waifuButton');

const makeImages = (waifus) => {
    for(let result of waifus) {
        const img = document.createElement('IMG');
        img.src.url = result.show.image.medium;
        document.body.append(img);
    }
}

waifuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('https://api.waifu.im/random')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.images)
            waifuImage.src = res.url;
            waifus = waifuImage;
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: waifuImage is a div. the one that has src attribute is the `waifus`. So it should be : `document.querySelector('#waifus');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues:

1. You are trying to set the src on the `div` rather than `img`
2. You are trying to set `res.url`, But the res doesn't have a URL. URL is in `res.images[0].url`.

```js
const waifuImage = document.querySelector('#waifus');
const waifuButton = document.querySelector('#waifuButton');

const makeImages = (waifus) => {
  for (let result of waifus) {
    const img = document.createElement('IMG');
    img.src.url = result.show.image.medium;
    document.body.append(img);
  }
}

waifuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  fetch('https://api.waifu.im/random')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      waifuImage.src = res.images[0].url;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

```css
#waifus {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="waifuContainer" class="container mt-5 text-center">
  <h1 class="display-5 text-warning" id="dadJokeFont">Click for waifu:</h1>
  <button id="waifuButton" class="btn btn-warning mt-5">uWu</button>
  <div id="waifuImage">
    <img id="waifus" src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```